# WSO2 API Manager with external oauth provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have an oAuth/OpenIDConnect provider running inside our organization. This is based on [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).

I would like to use this with WSO2 API Manager for both publisher and store portals to login and also as token provider. I read the documentation in WSO2 site and tried to setup this with WSO Identity Server but I cant find a clear explanation on how to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a third party key manager with WSO2 API Manager. Please follow the [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager).

WSO2 also has Identity Server which you can connect to WSO2 API Manager. You can find the details in the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager+in+WSO2+API+Manager). At the moment, you can find docs for API Manager 2.0.0 and docs will be available for API Manager 2.1.0 soon.